# Hiding and showing tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show and hide the tab bar in two differnt views.i used the code

```
  self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

its working fine in first view and in second view i am showing the Tabbar using same thing, but coming back to the first view it is not working.I used the code to go back is

```
     [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I cant use a pushViewController here because a number of classes redirected to this particular view.Exactly I want to hide the tab bar when I pop the view controller. please give me a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this line

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES`;

in `viewWillAppear` before push.

and use this line

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 1):

Try to hide/unhide the tabBar in the viewWillAppear: methods.
See if it works.
And let me know too :)